# Picking a discriminated union of type from a list

Tags: f#

I have a list of *Buffs* which are part of a discriminated union

```
type Buff =
    | Block of int
    | Thorns of int

let xs = [Block(5); Thorns(3)]
```

To get a buff from the list I do the following:

```
let tryPickBlock xs =
    xs
    |> List.tryPick (fun b ->
        match b with
        | Buff.Block b -> Some b
        | _ -> None)

let tryPickThorns xs =
    xs
    |> List.tryPick (fun t ->
        match t with
        | Buff.Thorns t -> Some t
        | _ -> None)
```

and then

```
xs |> tryPickBlock
```

or

```
xs |> tryPickThorns
```

but that means I have to write a tryPickXy function for every case of *Buff*.
Is there a more generic way to solve this? Something like:

```
let tryPickBuff<'T when 'T :> Buff> xs : 'T option=
    xs
    |> List.tryPick (fun t ->
        match t with
        | :? 'T as buff -> Some buff
        | _ -> None)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all your buffs have the same shape, you can refactor the type like this:

```ml
type BuffType =
    | Block
    | Thorns

type Buff =
    {
        BuffType : BuffType
        Value : int
    }
```

Then you can pick a buff value of a given type like this:

```ml
let tryPickBuff buffType xs =
    xs
    |> List.tryPick (fun buff ->
        if buff.BuffType = buffType then
            Some buff.Value
        else
            None)
```

You might also want to consider turning your list of buffs into a map:

```ml
type BuffMap = Map<BuffType, int>
```

Then you can use `Map.tryFind` to lookup a buff value more efficiently:

```ml
let tryFindBuff buffType (xs : BuffMap) =
    xs |> Map.tryFind buffType
```

Answer (score 1):

When you construct a union case, you need to deconstruct it eventually in order to retrieve the information contained therein. While you could take a few short-cuts with Reflection, you still need to get at that; for example having a tool that matches to case names does not relief you from the need to deconstruct ie. pattern match.

```
let tryFindCase name xs =
    let uci x = FSharpValue.GetUnionFields(x, x.GetType()) |> fst
    xs |> Seq.tryFind (fun x -> (uci x).Name = name)

tryFindCase "Block" [Block 5; Thorns 3]
// val it : Buff option = Some (Block 5)
```